# Displaying calculated data on simulation main window

Tags: anylogic

after running my simulation model, I have results that are printed on the console. instead of printing on the console, is there a way i can display results on simulation main. i mean once we run the model the simulation window pops up and we push the run button where the simulation main closes and the main window starts running, instead of that once the run button is pushed the simulation main window stays until the simulation is ended and the output is displayed later on simulation main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. First, untick this box in your sim experiment properties:
[image]

Next, drag in a button to your experiment and give it this code:

```
if ( getState() == IDLE ){
    run();
    getExperimentHost().setPresentable( this);
}
```

This starts the model but you stay at the experiment.

To display data, you use the code box below in the experiment using the `root` keyword to access `Main`:
[image]

NOTE: This only updates after the model run. If you want to see data updates during the run, you need to display it on `Main` directly (this is what it is for)